# Как правильней загружать видео, video src или iframe youtube?

Tags: html5, seo

Интересует вопрос загрузки видео на сайт, что лучше в плане сео-оптимизации и скорости загрузки, быстрее будет с помощью тегов `video` или `iframe src youtube`?

Comment: С помощью iframe, т.е. youTube сделал уже всё за вас (кодеки, плеер и прочее).

Comment: по мне так одинаково, только у **iframe** поддержка браузеров больше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Загрузка видео с использованием тэгов video или iframe предусматривает загрузки видеофайла в прямом потоке загрузки браузера. Это значит, что скорость загрузки, особенно для мобильных устрйоств будет понижена. Однако, **[эта скорость есть сигнал поискового ранга Гугл](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2018/01/using-page-speed-in-mobile-search.html)**.

Моё предложение для оптимизации:

Установите линк ютуб внутри кнопки или этикетки видео. В этом случае в потоке пямой загрузки будет участвовать только кнопка, что явно легче чем видеофайл.

Для предварительного соединения с ютуб используйте какие-то из мета линков **[Resource Hints](https://www.w3.org/TR/resource-hints/)**. Обычная рекомендация - это **preconnect**. Однако вы должны сами определить степень верояности открытия видео пользователем. Если видео есть важная часть содержания веб-страницы, то вам надо рассмотреть использование **prefetch** или даже **prerender**. Однако эти мета линки будут потреблять много ресурсов браузера и его работа может замедлиться. Поэтому вам надо определить оптимальный баланс между этими мета и степенью вероятности загрузки видео.

Если же видео является единственным содержанием вебстраницы, то вы можете использовать мета тэг **[preload](https://www.w3.org/TR/preload/)**. Установите этот мета в самом верху содержания *head*, сразу же после *meta charset=* и/или *meta name=robots*. В этом случае браузер загрузит ваше видео до разбора DOM и загрузки веб-страницы.